# Regular expression code for allowing at least alphabets or number with symbols

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am using following code for validation of data in jQuery like below

```
         return /^(?=.*[A-Za-z0-9/\$#.-_])[A-Za-z0-9/\$#.-_]$/i.test(value)
```

Actually I want the value should start with atleast alphabets or numbers or combination of both (alphabets and numbers) then it should allow to use these symbols / \ $ # .  -  _ after that.

For e.g

```
       1) a/
       2) 446/
       3) a4Z_
       4) a75/_@
```

These are allowed examples. The above code is not working. How can I get the right regular expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the following ticks your boxes:

```
^[a-z\d]+[\w\\\/$#.-]*$
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/0PsHaq/1).

- Note - Currently, "a75/_@" seems to be invalid as you didn't explicitly allowed the "@" in your character class. Include it if needed.
- Note - As in your own example I also used the case-insensitive flag. I guess a valid regex coded pattern would be `/^[a-z\d]+[\w\\\/$#.-]*$/gi`.

---

- `^` - Start string anchor.
- `[a-z\d]+` - 1+ alnum-chars from the given class.
- `[\w\\\/$#.-]*` - 0+ chars from the give class.
- `$` - End string anchor.

Comment: Thanks for the help but it is not allowing uppercase of alphabets.... Please add them also and update your answer

Comment: @Nida, can you be more explicit with what it doesn't allow? Maybe with an example it doesn't match as yet? Note that `\w` is shorthand for `[A-Za-z0-9_]`, and the "i"-flag should allow for both upper- and lowercase alpha.